# Azure pipeline hangs indefinitely after updating to webpack 5 and nodejs 18 on step with webpack build

Tags: node.js, azure, webpack, devops, pipeline

After updating webpack to 5 version and node js to 18.16.0, azure devops pipeline hangs indefinitely on webpack build step. No errors and etc. Npm install step works fine.
On local pc works fine. Tried changing build agent vmImage version to win 2022, adding python install step, cleaning npm cache etc.
My yaml, package json and webpack config is in attachment.

```
name: MySpa
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2022'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'ReleaseSPA'
 

steps:
- script: |
    choco install python2 --version=2.7.18
    refreshenv
  displayName: 'Install Python 2.7'
  
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
    
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: Install Node.js
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '18.16.0'

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'custom' 
    customCommand: 'cache clean --force'

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
    workingDir: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\MySpa\'

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'custom' 
    customCommand: 'install -g webpack webpack-cli'
    
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
   command: 'custom'
   workingDir: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\MySpa\'
   customCommand: 'run build:prod'
  timeoutInMinutes: 15

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

  
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy published files to Deployment folder.'
  inputs:
    sourceFolder: $(build.artifactStagingDirectory)
    TargetFolder: $(DeploymentFolder)\MySpa_Build$(Build.BuildId)
    Contents: |
      **\*
      !**\*.cs
      !**\*.csproj
    CleanTargetFolder: true


- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    artifact: 'MySpa_Build$(Build.BuildId)'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

```
"use strict";

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
let oidcHtmlType = ["callback.html", "silent-renew.html"];
const applicationBasePath = "./VueApp/";

// Plugins
const miniCssExtractPlugin = new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: "css/[name]/main.css",
    chunkFilename: "css/[id].css"
});

var appEntryFiles = {};
fs.readdirSync(applicationBasePath).forEach(function (name) {

    let spaEntryPoint = applicationBasePath + name + '/app.ts';

    if (fs.existsSync(spaEntryPoint)) {
        appEntryFiles[name] = spaEntryPoint;
    }

    spaEntryPoint = applicationBasePath + name + '/app.js';
    if (fs.existsSync(spaEntryPoint)) {
        appEntryFiles[name] = spaEntryPoint;
    }

});

appEntryFiles["vendor"] = [
    path.resolve(__dirname, "VueApp/common/design/site.scss"),
];

module.exports = function (env, argv) {
    return {
        entry: appEntryFiles,
        stats: { warnings: true},
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, "wwwroot/dist"),
            filename: "js/[name]/bundle.js",
            chunkFilename: "js/[name]/bundle.js?v=[chunkhash]",
            publicPath: "/dist/",
            clean: true,
            hashFunction: "xxhash64"
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".vue", ".json", "scss", "css"],
            alias: {
                vue$: "vue/dist/vue.esm.js",
                "@": path.join(__dirname, applicationBasePath)
            }
        },
        devtool: "source-map",
        devServer: {
            historyApiFallback: true,
            noInfo: true,
            overlay: true
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.css$/i,
                    use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.vue$/,
                    loader: "vue-loader",
                    options: {
                        preserveWhitespace: false,
                        loaders: {
                            scss: "vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader", // <style lang="scss">
                            sass: "vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax" // <style lang="sass">
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                },
                {
                    test: /\.ts$/,
                    loader: "ts-loader",
                    options: {
                        appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
                        transpileOnly: true
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
                    use: [
                        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        'css-loader',
                        {
                            loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true
                            }
                        },
                        'sass-loader'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        "css-loader"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jpe?g)(\?.*)?$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'url-loader',
                            options: {
                                limit: 4096,
                                fallback: {
                                    loader: 'file-loader',
                                    options: {
                                        name: 'img/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(svg)(\?.*)?$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'file-loader',
                            options: {
                                name: 'img/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/i,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'url-loader',
                            options: {
                                limit: 4096,
                                fallback: {
                                    loader: 'file-loader',
                                    options: {
                                        name: 'fonts/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: '[name].css',
            }),
            miniCssExtractPlugin,
            new VueLoaderPlugin(),

            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
            }),
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                Promise: "es6-promise-promise",
                Vue: ["vue/dist/vue.esm.js", "default"]
            }),

            new CopyWebpackPlugin({
                patterns: [
                    {
                        from: 'node_modules/oidc-client/dist/oidc-client.min.js',
                        to: 'js'
                    },
                    {
                        from: 'node_modules/@auth0/auth0-spa-js/dist/auth0-spa-js.development.js',
                        to: 'js'
                    },
                    //From flatten
                    {
                        from: path.join(applicationBasePath, `${oidcHtmlType[1]}`),
                        to: "../silent-renew.html",
                        noErrorOnMissing: true,
                        transform(content, path) {
                            return content.toString().replace(
                                /<base.*href=".*".*>/i,
                                '<base href="/" />'
                            );
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        from: path.join(applicationBasePath, `${oidcHtmlType[0]}`),
                        to: "../callback.html",
                        noErrorOnMissing: true,
                        transform(content, path) {
                            return content.toString().replace(
                                /<base.*href=".*".*>/i,
                                '<base href="/" />'
                            );
                        },
                    },

                ]
            })
        ],
        optimization: {
            minimize: true,
            minimizer: [
                new CompressionPlugin({
                    test: /\.(js|css|html)$/,
                    filename: '[path][base].gz',
                    algorithm: 'gzip',
                }),
            ],
        },
    };
};
```

```
{
  "name": "stock-management-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "NordicOil", 
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode none",
    "build:dev": "webpack --mode development --config webpack.config.js",
    "build:prod": "webpack --mode production --progress --config webpack.config.js",
    "publish": "npm install && webpack --mode production --config webpack.config.js && dotnet publish --configuration Release",
    "test": "jest",
    "watch-dev": "webpack --mode none --watch --color"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-spa-js": "^1.16.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.26",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.12.0",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.9",
    "@mdi/font": "^5.3.45",
    "axios": "0.18.0",
    "bulmaswatch": "^0.7.5",
    "core-util-is": "^1.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "oidc-client": "^1.7.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "vee-validate": "^2.2.3",
    "vue": "2.5.22",
    "vue-flatpickr-component": "8.1.1",
    "vue-json-compare": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-json-component": "0.3.0",
    "vue-multiselect": "2.1.3",
    "vue-notification": "1.3.14",
    "vue-router": "3.0.2",
    "vuex": "3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "3.3.29",
    "@types/node": "10.12.18",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.28",
    "babel-core": "6.26.3",
    "babel-jest": "29.5.0",
    "babel-loader": "9.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "2.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "6.26.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-export-extensions": "6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "6.23.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "6.24.1",
    "buefy": "^0.8.20",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "10.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "11.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "es6-promise-promise": "1.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "2.7.5",
    "file-loader": "6.2.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest-serializer-vue": "2.0.2",
    "resolve-url-loader": "3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "13.2.2",
    "sass": "1.62.1",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "ts-loader": "9.4.2",
    "typescript": "5.0.4",
    "url-loader": "4.1.1",
    "vue-class-component": "6.3.2",
    "vue-jest": "3.0.2",
    "vue-json-component": "0.3.0",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.8",
    "vue-property-decorator": "9.1.2",
    "vue-style-loader": "4.1.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.5.22",
    "webpack": "5.75.0",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin":"5.0.0",
    "webpack-cli": "5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "4.11.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.25.3",
    "webpack-merge": "5.8.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "5.3.7", 
    "cssnano": "6.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "vue"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/VueApp/$1"
    },
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      ".*\\.(vue)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest"
    },
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-serializer-vue"
    ],
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "<rootDir>/VueApp/**/*.{js,vue}",
      "!**/node_modules/**"
    ]   
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

I tried changing build agent, tried installing python 2.7, adding steps with npm cache clean.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I fixed it myself. Webpack 5 by default uses watch on. False flag did not work, and I found crunch fix for that.

```
     apply: (compiler) => {
          compiler.hooks.done.tap("DonePlugin", (stats) => {
            console.log("Compile is done !");
            setTimeout(() => {
              process.exit(0);
            });
          });
        },
      },
```